# Не загрузить файл на сервер с node.js multiparty

Tags: node.js

Не получается загрузить файл на сервер с *multiparty*

```
var mpForm = new multiparty.Form();
mpForm.parse(req, function(err, fields, files, fieldsList, filesList) {
        console.log(err) ;
}
```

В консоль всегда выводиться

> [Error: Request aborted]

На клиенте события `upload` формируются правильно, файл реально загружается на сервер (появляется в системной папке `tmp` c именем `upload_xxxxxxx`)

Comment: Попробуйте поискать в баг трекере гитхаба: https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=aborted

Comment: Файл уже появляется на сервере в `tmp` до вызова `parse()`? Если да,  то кто-то уже обрабатывает multipart-часть вашего запроса и вам не нужно использовать multiparty

Comment: Да.  Появляется до.....  Получатся что обработку загрузки файлов express делает сам автоматически?  А для меня это обычный post запрос?

Comment: Проверил, действительно все работает без multiparty

Comment: @Кирилл, правильно ли я понимаю, что ваша проблема решена?